# Create SLOW SUBSCRIBER in KDB+

Tags: kdb

I am trying to simulate a **slow subscriber** in KDB+.
I don't think I need to load the **.u.q** file and initialize `.u.init` since the table is already in the publish list of **TP** which I verified using `.z.w`

As the tab is in publish list, I am not opening the handle to **TP**.
Therefore, to simulate a "slow subscriber" I am just using the system sleep command.

The issue is, the table is getting populated on the **RDB** side but I cannot see it in queue when I use `.z.W` on **TP**

On **TP** side I have below sample data to be published to **RDB**

```
q) data:([]time:99?.z.p; sym:99?`AAPL`GOOG`AAPL; table:99?tab1`tab2`tab3; size:99?53.54)
q) .u.pub[`tab;data]
q) count each .z.W  //This is not showing msgs in buffer
```

On **RDB** side I have

```
q) system "sleep 500"
```

When I use `` .u.sub[`tab;`] `` I am getting -> `"Table tab is not in list of stp pub/sub tables"` which is wierd.
FYI I am using TorQ architecture.

Comment: Have you defined a schema for `tab`? See this documentation if not https://code.kx.com/q/wp/rt-tick/#tickerplant-tp

Comment: Yeah, I have..!

Comment: Is `tab` in `.u.t`? If not it will throw an error. Also, you don't seem to use the Plain Vanilla Tick setup as the error you get is not in the code base. This is the line where it would check for `t` to be in `.u.t`. https://github.com/KxSystems/kdb-tick/blob/master/tick/u.q#L16
If you just want to simulate a slow subscriber, check out TICK from KX, start all processes, simulate a feedhandler and then just block the RDB.

Comment: Checked, the tab is present in .u.t.
Yup, you're right. This architecture is on top of the Vanilla.

Comment: I suspect your data isn't big enough to register in the output queue .... trying sending 100000 times that much data